# Does sklearn support kernel regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I read about kernel regression:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression

[image]

- Does `sklearn` contains this regression ?
- I saw `sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge` but it don't seems to be the same.
- Do I need to implement the kernel regression or `sklearn` has it's own kernel regression models (with different types of kernels) ?

Comment: I don't think there is one.  A bunch of kernel functions are available, though https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#pairwise-metrics.  Perhaps you need to calculate the weighted average on your own.

Comment: In statsmodel, this may be what you look for: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression.KernelReg.html